# Reactjs: child component not showing after clicking button from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have four components. 1: Navigation, 2: Home, 3: Group, 4: GroupsChild.

In the navigation component there are two component and a `Button`. When I click the button it shows `GroupsChild` component properly.

But when I click `Group` first, and then click the button (named `Click Me` in `Navigation`), **it doesn't show the `GroupsChild` component**. I think the problem is in `Group.js` in `componentDidMount`.

What should I change?

Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Group from './Group';
import Home from './Home';

class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state={
            home: true,
            group: false,
            num: null,
        }
    }
    home=()=>{
        this.setState({home:true, group:false})
    }
    group=()=>{
        this.setState({home:false, group:true})
    }
    click=()=>{
        this.setState({home:false, group:true, num:1})// i want to pass the num
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div onClick={this.home} className='col half'>Home</div>
                    <div onClick={this.group} className='col half'>Group</div>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.click}>Click Me</button><br/>
                ---------------------------
            {this.state.home?(<Home/>):null}
            {this.state.group?(<Group num={this.state.num}/>):null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Navigation;
```

Group.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GroupsChild from './GroupsChild';

class Group extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state={
            child: false,
        }
    }
    child=()=>{
        this.setState({child:true})
    }
    componentDidMount(){ //  <<<--------- here is the problem
        if(this.props.num !== null){
            this.setState({child:true})
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Group</h1>
                <button onClick={this.child}>Child</button>
            {this.state.child?(<GroupsChild/>):null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Group;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                home
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

GroupsChild.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GroupsChild extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                Groups Child
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GroupsChild;
```

I've another problem. It's annoying but please solve this.
When I click `Group` first then `Click me` then `Home` then again `Group` , it should show only `Group` component, not also `GroupsChild`.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you try changing your onclick to `onClick={() => this.click()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I click `Group` first, and then click the button (named "Click
> Me" in `Navigation`), it doesn't show the `GroupsChild` component. I think
> the problem is in `Group.js` in `componentDidMount`.

Seems you need to also implement `componentDidUpdate` in `Group`. When the state in `Navigation` sets `group` true and doesn't set the `num` state, then `Group` is mounted with the undefined `num` prop value.

```
class Group extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            child: false,
        }
    }
    child = () => {
        this.setState({ child: true });
    }
    checkNum = () => {
        if (this.props.num !== null) {
            this.setState({ child: true });
        }
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.checkNum();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.num !== this.props.num) {
            this.checkNum();
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Group</h1>
                <button onClick={this.child}>Child</button>
                {this.state.child ? (<GroupsChild/>) : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

> I've another problem. it's annoying but please solve this. when i
> click Group first then Click me then Home then again Group , it should
> show only Group component, not also GroupsChild.

I think this may be a case where you need to "reset" or "unset" the `num` state in `Navigation` when clicking "Home".

```
class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            home: true,
            group: false,
            num: null,
        }
    }

    home = () => {
        this.setState({
            home:true,
            group:false,
            num: null, // <-- reset back to null
        });
    }

    ...
```

Comment: sir, it shows error. Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: @AsifBiswas Ack, quite right. I thought I could run the same logic in both lifecycle methods but yeah, you can't indiscriminately update state in `componentDidUpdate`, you need to actually compare current props to previous props. Sorry about that, please check again.